# CSV file into an array

Tags: python, csv

I have this script that scans a csv file and if the value in the first `column == 200` it saves that row into an array.

The problem is, I need to save that row and the next 10 rows in that same array.  What can I add to the script so it does that? I tried to do `for row in len(10):` but I get an error.

```
p = csv.reader(open('file.csv'), delimiter=';')
a=[0]*2881
a = numpy.array(a, dtype=dict)
for row in p:
       if row[0]=="200":
          a=row
          break
print a
```

Comment: What exactly is `a` supposed to be? You're specifying a `dtype` of `dict`, but then feeding it a bunch of `0`s. And later, you do `a=row`, throwing away whatever you managed to create. Can you explain what you actually want in `a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to figure out exactly what you want, but I'm going to try to guess.

Maybe you want `a` to be a `list` of the 11 rows from the CSV starting from the first one with `200` in the first column:

```
p = csv.reader(open('file.csv'), delimiter=';')
for row in p:
    if row[0]=="200":
        a = [row] + list(itertools.islice(p, 10))
        break
```

In English: `a` is a list of the found row, plus a list of the next 10 rows.

If you want that to be stored in a `numpy` array instead of a `list`, it's much easier to construct the array from the list after this loop than to construct the array in advance and try to add to it on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
#!/usr/local/pypy-1.9/bin/pypy

import csv

def gen():
    with open('file.csv', 'rb') as file_:
        reader = csv.reader(file_, delimiter=';')
        state = 'no feed'
        for row in reader:
            if row[0]=="200":
                yield row
                state = 'feed'
                count = 1
            elif state == 'feed':
                if count < 10:
                    yield row
                    count += 1
                if count >= 10:
                    state = 'no feed'
                    count = 0

print list(gen())
```

Answer (score -1):

give this a go:

```
p = csv.reader(open('file.csv'), delimiter=';')

# walk through p, and look for '200' 
for i, row in enumerate(p):
    if row[0] == '200':
        my_array = numpy.array([x for x in p[i:i+11])
```

Should return an array with the row your interested in, plus the next 10

Hope this helps!

Comment: This will raise an exception, because a `csv.reader` isn't indexable. (More importantly, it's just an iterator, not an iterable, so there is _no way_ to access any rows but the upcoming ones, unless you've stored them somewhere.)